# How to detect whether Java is Enabled in Java preferences through JavaScript (browser)

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I have a page which loads an applet. I'm using the Oracle's deployJava.js to detect whether Java is installed on the system, and I make a call to applet.getAppletInfo() to determine whether the applet is up and running. However, I cannot determine whether Java is actually enabled. I manually disabled Java through the control panel (java preferences) and now all IE browsers freeze when the getAppletInfo() call is made.

Is there a way to detect whether Java is Enabled in Java Preferences prior to making any calls to the applet? `navigator.javaEnabled()` just gives you info on whether Java is enabled on the browser, but not on the system.

Comment: Maybe in JavaScript try { java.lang.String s = "x"; } catch? Or < NOAPPLET >?

Comment: Doesn't work... Actually, if I can only find a solution for IE browsers not to freeze, but to be able to determine whether the applet is up and running, if would be sufficient.